# dealing with an error from a typed WebAPI HttpClient call

Tags: asp.net-web-api, error-handling, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I have a number of calls I make to a webapi client which return a Task 
something like this

```
public async Task<TResp> GetMyThingAsync(TReq req)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURI);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

        await HttpRuntime.Cache.GetToken().ContinueWith((t) =>
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("XXX", t.Result);
        });

        var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<TReq>("This/That/", req);
        httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var resp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResp>();
        return resp;
    }
}
```

the calls to the api can of course return 500's or some other problem. `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` obviously throws if something like that happens, but then its too late to do anything with any information in the response. 
is there a nice way of dealing with this?
I understand you can add a messageHandler with the client, something like
`HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory(new ErrorMessageHandler())` ..

```
var customHandler = new ErrorMessageHandler()
        { InnerHandler = new HttpClientHandler()};
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(customHandler);
```

is this the way to go? what would the ErroMessageHandler look like and do to return something useful to the calling controller...?

thanks muchly

nat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a custom handler can be an elegant solution to go about logging the exception or validating the response. I am not sure if the called controller is waiting for a meaningful response from the clients end if it encounters an exception. I think the real important part is to make sure you (the client) handle the web apis errors gracefully.

This can be done in a couple of ways:

1. You can handle exceptions locally inside the calling method. You can use the `HttpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode` property which indicated if a bad response returned instead of calling `httpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` which throws an exception, and return a custom ErrorResponse (or do whatever you decide):

   ```
   var client = new HttpClient() // No need to dispose HttpClient

   client.BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseURI);
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();

   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

   var token = await HttpRuntime.Cache.GetToken();
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("XXX", token);

   var httpResponseMessage = await client.PostAsXmlAsync<TReq>("This/That/", req);
   if (!httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
   {
      return Task.FromResult(new ErrorResponse()) // Create some kind of error response to indicate failure
   }

   var resp = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsAsync<TResp>();
   return resp;
   ```
2. Create a ErrorLoggingHandler which can log exceptions (or do something else) received from the web api:

   ```
   public class ErrorLoggingHandler : DelegatingHandler
   {
      private readonly StreamWriter _writer; // As a sample, log to a StreamWriter

      public ErrorLoggingHandler(Stream stream)
      {
         _writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
      }

      protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
      {
         var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

         if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             // This would probably be replaced with real error 
             // handling logic (return some kind of special response etc..)
             _writer.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", request.RequestUri,
               (int) response.StatusCode, response.Headers.Date);
         }

         return response;
      }

      protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
      {
         if (disposing)
         {
            _writer.Dispose();
         }

         base.Dispose(disposing);
      }
   }
   ```

Then, you can create your `HttpClient` using `HttpClientFactory`:

```
var httpclient = HttpClientFactory.Create(new ErrorLoggingHandler(new FileStream(@"Location", FileMode.OpenOrCreate)));
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, but I cannot return anything other than my typed response (i presume - possibly wrongly) from the GetMyThingAsync method as it only returns a TResp (or whatever), so how can I get it to return an ErrorResponse ?
likewise with the DelegatingHandler, I can log stuff, but how can I get stuff back to the controller without throwing an exception?

Comment: what type is `TResp`? what does it contain? also, why are you bound to it? is the controller waiting couting on your returning a valid response?

Comment: hi Yuval, maybe foolishly all my calls return typed responses from the methods themselves.. so a call to the GetAvailability method will return an AvailabilityResponse object.. should i instead be creating a more generic client that I can dissect at a later point if it hasnt returned me a generic HttpMessageResponse that is faulted..?
I wanted to use DelgatingHandlers to deal with adding in the authorization headers , rather than duplicating that for each different method. so maybe some generic thing would be more appropriate

Comment: basically I have a number of API calls to make, all returning different objects for which I have classes for, I have written a method for each, returning a typed result

Comment: Your Response object can all derive from a common `ResponseBase` which has a `StatusCode` property and an `Exception` property which will be filled in case there was an error/exception getting data

Comment: Good luck. Post another question if it doesn't work out as you expected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55331/discussion-between-nat-and-yuval-itzchakov).

Comment: Thank you, @YuvalItzchakov! A tried and trusted way of using a `ResponseObject` has just rescued me from being lost in a forest of aync calls and responses colluding with too many EF exceptions with GUI client validation turned off.

Comment: @ProfK Glad it helped :)